# Show that its a Generalized Eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Show that the minimizer is obtained by a generalized eigenvalue problem.
>
> $$\alpha=\underset{1^TK\alpha=0; \ \alpha^TK^2\alpha=1}{\text {arg min}}   \gamma ||f||_{K}^2+f^TLf$$

Details:
$K$ is a constant reproducing Kernel matrix with real entries, and is positive semi-definite and the entries in the matrix are obtained through a Mercer Kernel $k:X\times X$ and has a reproducing kernel Hilbert space of functions $\mathcal{H}_K$ defined from $X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ associated with a corrsponding norm being $||.||_K$. Also, $f$ is real-valued, $\gamma$ is positive and $L$ is a constant p.s.d matrix with real entries.

Reference: Eq 13 in the paper-
[http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~niyogi/papersps/BNSaistats.pdf](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Eniyogi/papersps/BNSaistats.pdf)
The minimization problem posted above is posed in the paper  and the authors give the solution in terms of a generalized eigen value problem. I am having trouble trying to pose the minimization as a generalized eigen value problem.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? What is $K$? And what is $L$? Is $\gamma$ positive? Is $f$ real valued?

Comment: @bartgol Sure! Posted these updates in the question.